# App shows black screen on app bundle, but fine on android studio debug

Tags: android, flutter

I just started to learn android app development. My app work fine on android studio. I use flutter sdk to code.

But when I create an app bundle, use bundletool to run on my phone. It only show blank screen.

I dont know what to show here, help me please !
Thanks for advice!

When I change channel to dev channel, i have this issue on run:

> `/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Info: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct { ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Info: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct { ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Info: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {} ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Info: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {} ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Info: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {} ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Info: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {} ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Info: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class CLSID extends Struct {} ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Info: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class STATSTG extends Struct {} ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Info: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {} ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Info: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class Utf8 extends Struct { ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Info: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead. class Utf16 extends Struct { ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Info: Support for using non-constant type arguments 'T' in this FFI API is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Rewrite the code to ensure that type arguments are compile time constants referring to a valid native type. final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();`

Comment: you can use `flutter run --release` command. This will  compiles to release mode.

Comment: Does your phone have all the right permissions?  The one that most people are tripping on is that you need explicit position to connect to the internet and even to other devices on your local network.

Comment: I have use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>. I only add it to AndroidMainfest. Am i need to create something to let user agree it ?